# Can you skin a UIButton application wide in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

Anywhere there is a UIButton in my app i would like it to have a specific background image. This background image will always be the same.

What i dont want to have to do is call a method on every button that i put into my UI.

Can i do this via a category or something similar?

Comment: Have you considered subclassing and doing it from there? Interface builder let's you choose the class. Also, I saw something like a Objective-C extension mechanism. "ClassName+Extension" whereas ClassName is a existing class. Not sure if that would work out for u.

Comment: What you call "extension" is known as a category.

Comment: in the WWDC 2011 keynote on the slides for iOS 5 SDK, there was the word "Customize UI". This will answer your question.

Comment: Yep, but iOS5 is under NDA...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change global appearance of your button via simple code (in current SDK).

---

**BUT**, You can subclass your `UIButton`. For example:

```
.h

@interface MyButton : UIButton

@end

---

.m

@implementation MyButton

// your customization code

@end
```

And if you want to insert an UIButton instance like:

```
UIButton *button = // init your button
// customize your button
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

you have to change `UIButton` to `MyButton`

```
Mybutton *button=  // init your button
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Don't forget about `#import "MyButton.h"` in your **.m** / **.h** file.

---

**EDIT:** Where should you make customizations:

```
@implementation UIButton (MyCategory)

+ (id)buttonWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    return [[[self alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    // HERE YOU CAN DO SOME CUSTOMIZATION
  }
  return self;
}
```

Then, somewhere in your viewController:

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

or:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
```

Comment: This is the situation I wanted to avoid. I was more looking down the category route to globally override one of the UIButtons methods. If I did it the way you suggested I would be left with a lot of UI positioning logic in my implementation files for every button I add to the UI. In my opinion that is not acceptable. Why can't I Skin/Template a button like most other MVC based UI technologies? Hmmmm...

Comment: Of course, you can create UIButton category. The you have to insert `#import` at the top of your files **or** insert it in your prefix (.pch) file.

Comment: And which method am I to override in my category to give the button a background image?

Comment: I managed to use a category in pretty much the way you outlined, only i let the XIB file handle the positioning

Comment: OK, you can do it in that way too ;)

Comment: @Kashiv From [Apple's own documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1), overriding methods in categories works, but is strongly discouraged. You really should consider just subclassing UIButton.